# How to increase readin time of Zarr file?

Tags: geospatial, dask, ram, python-xarray

I am using xarray and Dask to process geospatial data. I have to process the data by year to stay within the bounds of my RAM.

I have a large file called uv_ds_120m_with_density which is roughly 2TB in size. It has the following properties

```
Dimensions:  (Time: 525936, south_north: 453, west_east: 630)
Coordinates:
  * Time (Time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01 ... 2019-12-31T23:30:11
    lat  (south_north, west_east) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(227, 315), meta=np.ndarray>
    lon  (south_north, west_east) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(227, 315), meta=np.ndarray>
Dimensions without coordinates: south_north, west_east
Data variables:
    RHO (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(360, 29, 79), meta=np.ndarray>
    U   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(360, 29, 79), meta=np.ndarray>
    V   (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(360, 29, 79), meta=np.ndarray>
```

I process the smaller subset like so:

```
datasets = []

for i in range(2005,2006):
    for j in range(1,13):
        print (f'{i}-{j}')

        # Taking a subset of this dataset to process
        subset = ds.sel(Time=slice(f'{i}-{j}',f'{i}-{j}'))
        # Wind Speed calculation
        ws = np.sqrt(np.square(subset.U) + np.square(subset.V))

        # Define the chunk size for each dimension
        chunk_size = {'Time': 100, 'south_north': -1, 'west_east': -1}

        # Chunk the dataset using Dask
        ds_chunked = subset.chunk(chunk_size)

        # Perform the calculation for each chunk (now in a lazy manner)
        ws = np.sqrt(np.square(ds_chunked.U) + np.square(ds_chunked.V))
        WH = np.ceil(ws * 2) / 2
        WL = np.floor(ws * 2) / 2
        Rho_H = (np.ceil(ds_chunked.RHO * 40) / 40)
        Rho_L = (np.floor(ds_chunked.RHO * 40) / 40)

        WH = WH.where(WH > 3.0, 0)
        WH = WH.where(WH < 24.5, 24.5)
        WL = WL.where(WL > 3, 0)
        WL = WL.where(WL < 24.5, 24.5)

        Rho_L = Rho_L.where(Rho_L > 0.95, 0.95)
        Rho_L = Rho_L.where(Rho_L < 1.275, 1.275)
        Rho_L = Rho_L.astype(str)

        # Assuming da is already defined and it's a lookup table
        power = da.sel(row=WH, column=Rho_L)
        power = (power / 2)
        power.name = 'Power_Curve'
        power_curve_dataset = power.to_dataset()

        # Append each month's dataset to the list
        datasets.append(power_curve_dataset)

#Concatenate all datasets along the 'Time' dimension
ds_combined = xr.concat(datasets[0:12], dim='Time')

# Save to Zarr store on disk instead of persisting to memory
ds_combined.to_zarr("S://Power_by_year//Power_2005.zarr", mode='w')
```

I take a smaller subset of this file which is a single year, run a power curve and then export the file. Reading in the uv_ds_120m_with_density takes quick, but reading in the smaller Power_2005 takes ages.

Can anyone explain why, and maybe how to prevent such long read in times?

Comment: Please include the exact lines you use to open the original and derived datasets

Comment: Thanks @mdurant for your reply. After much trial and error i found the right chunk sizes to open the files quickly

Comment: In that case, please answer your own question with any helpful things you learned, so that it can be helpful to others.